# Jquery Context Menu plug in stops working if name of div is anything other than container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I am trying to use this plug https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu/blob/master/README.md

However if i rename container class to anything other than container it stops working.

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/jquery.ui-contextmenu.min.js"></script>


<div id="container1">
    <div class="hasmenu">AAA</div>
    <div class="hasmenu">BBB</div>
    <div class="hasmenu">CCC</div>
</div>


$("#container1").contextmenu({
    delegate: ".hasmenu",
    menu: [
        {title: "Copy", cmd: "copy", uiIcon: "ui-icon-copy"},
        {title: "----"},
        {title: "More", children: [
            {title: "Sub 1", cmd: "sub1"},
            {title: "Sub 2", cmd: "sub1"}
            ]}
        ],
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert("select " + ui.cmd + " on " + ui.target.text());
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change in the plugin file of context menu. 
i mean may be you add there .container while making a default call.
because otherwise it's not possible

Comment: I didnt not change anything in plug in file. Just here. There is no `container` in it anyways.

Comment: Then you must check the console errors. if they are not there i will go for suicide :P

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're chaining the `.contextmenu` on the `#container1` .. if you want to work under a different name make sure you update the reference on both HTML and JS.

HTML: `<div id="#foo"> .. </div>`
JS: `$("#foo").contextmenu({ .. })`

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working with any ID/Class. See the snippet below. I did use the latest CDN version I could find. There might be a bug in the version you are using.

```js
$("#adifferentid").contextmenu({
  delegate: ".hasmenu",
  menu: [{
    title: "Copy",
    cmd: "copy",
    uiIcon: "ui-icon-copy"
  }, {
    title: "----"
  }, {
    title: "More",
    children: [{
      title: "Sub 1",
      cmd: "sub1"
    }, {
      title: "Sub 2",
      cmd: "sub1"
    }]
  }],
  select: function(event, ui) {
    alert("select " + ui.cmd + " on " + ui.target.text());
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.ui-contextmenu/1.9.0/jquery.ui-contextmenu.min.js"></script>


<div id="adifferentid">
  <div class="hasmenu">AAA</div>
  <div class="hasmenu">BBB</div>
  <div class="hasmenu">CCC</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is strange, I just copy pasted what you have posted, its not working. Then I just renamed it to `container` its working.

Comment: This seems more like a conflict in your scripts. Are you using any other javascripts?

Comment: Just Jquery, but i am however using multiple jquery plugins on the form

Comment: I suggest you remove each plugin one by one until it works again so you can figure out which plugin it is. (At least that is my hunch)